# Borrar contenido de Coleccion MongoDB desde Databricks con Python

Tags: python, mongodb, azure, databricks

Necesito borrar el contenido de una colección de MongoDB (truncate, NO hacer drop).

Estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
  
# Making Connection
myclient = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://****@****.g56cp.mongodb.net")
  
# database
db = myclient["intellitur"]
  
# Created or Switched to collection
Collection = db["calendari_jar"]

db.members.deleteMany()
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me sale el siguiente error:

```
'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'deleteMany' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

¿Sabéis que puede ser?. Es como si me faltara importar otra librería?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he optado por borrar (DROP) la coleccion, ya que luego la puedo crear fácilmente al insertarle datos

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
  
# Making Connection
myclient = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://ptddctti-dev:ptddctti-dev@ptddctti-mdb-cluster-pl-0.g56cp.mongodb.net")

# database
db = myclient["intellitur"]

# coleccion
Collection=db["calendari_jar"]
Collection.drop()
```